# Documentation for bash arguments

Tags: bash, scripting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does passing the -xe parameters to /bin/bash do](https://serverfault.com/questions/391255/what-does-passing-the-xe-parameters-to-bin-bash-do)

Where is the best place to read documentation on what parameters that are passed to bash such as `-x` and `-e` are? I tried the `man 1 bash`, but it doesn't seem to be covered there.