# What does passing the -xe parameters to /bin/bash do

Tags: bash, scripting

Exactly what the title says. I'm not having much luck finding the proper documentation to see what -xe does in the following use case:

`#!/bin/bash -xe`

what do those parameters do and where it is documented?

Comment: Are you talking about parameters that are passed to the BASH binary, or are you talking about functions and parameters within the BASH scripting language?

Comment: Referring to the parameters that are passed to the BASH binary, such as:  #!/bin/bash -xe

Answer (score 76, accepted):

If you read the man page for `bash` you'll find the following at the top of the `OPTIONS` section:

```
 All of the  single-character shell options documented in the
 description of the set builtin command can be used as options when the
 shell is invoked. In addition, bash interprets the following options
 when it is invoked...
```

And if you read the documentation for the `set` command later on in the man page, you'll find:

```
 -e      Exit  immediately  if a pipeline (which may consist of a
 single simple command),  a subshell command enclosed in parentheses,
 or one of the commands executed as part of a command list enclosed by
 braces (see SHELL GRAMMAR above) exits with a non-zero  status. 

 -x      After expanding each simple command, for command, case
 command, select command, or arithmetic  for  command,  display
 the  expanded value of PS4, followed by the command and its
 expanded arguments or associated word list.
```

In other words, `-e` makes the shell exit immediately whenever
something returns an error (this is often used in shell scripts as a
failsafe mechanism), and `-x` enables verbose execution of scripts so
that you can see what's happening.

Answer (score 14):

Type the following on your console to get an explanation of the BASH arguments:

```
bash -c "help set"
```

To answer your question:

`-e` Exit immediately if a command exits with a non-zero status.

`-x` Print commands and their arguments as they are executed.

Comment: Or just `help set`?

Comment: @Nagev To get the bash version of `help set` regardless of what shell you're using, the full command is necessary.

Answer (score 4):

From the [manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/bash.1.html):

> All of the single-character shell options documented in the description of the set builtin command can be used as options when the shell is invoked.

So have a look at the [set builtin](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/bash.1.html#contenttoc30).

Answer (score 2):

Are you thinking of the stuff where you do set -x set -e set -...? running `help set` gives those.

Comment: I'm thinking of parameters used such as the following: #!/bin/bash -xe

Answer (score 1):

I use excellent [Bash Reference Manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html) as one-stop documentation for Bash language. I found it more useful than man pages. The section relevant for you (description of -e, -x switches can be found here: [set builtin](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#The-Set-Builtin)

Answer (score 0):

> Where is the best place to read documentation on what parameters that are passed to bash 
>   such as -x and -e are? I tried the man 1 bash, but it doesn't seem to be covered there.

Read the OPTIONS section of the basj manpage.